# how to check end of stream in R stream package

Tags: r, data-stream

I am new in R programming. i am facing a problem related to Stream.
i am reading a data stream file from text file. when a stream reached end of stream. i am unable to handle this problem.

```
 Micro_cluster<-function(data_stream)
   {
     list_counter<-1;
  micro_clusters<-list();
  while(TRUE)
  {
     points<-DSD_Wrapper(get_points(data_stream,n=1000));
     if(!points)
     {
        print("End of Stream");    
     }
     else
     {
       mcluster<-DSC_DenStream();
       cluster(mcluster,points,n=1000);
       micro_clusters[list_counter]<-list(mcluster);
       list_counter<-list_counter+1;
       rm(mcluster);    
     }

  }
  rm(list_counter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't necessarily answer the *specific* problem without seeing what you're trying to stream in, but - you know that you're not actually ending that WHILE loop, right? It's just going to iterate forever. Presumably you want something like...

```
#Set an object that handles the boolean for the while loop, so that you can actually kill said loop
while_check <- TRUE

while(while_check)
{
 points<-DSD_Wrapper(get_points(data_stream,n=1000));
 if(!points)
 {
    print("End of Stream");
    #If there aren't any entries left, change that value so that the loop stops.
    while_check <- FALSE

 }
 else
 {
   mcluster<-DSC_DenStream();
   cluster(mcluster,points,n=1000);
   micro_clusters[list_counter]<-list(mcluster);
   list_counter<-list_counter+1;
   rm(mcluster);    
 }

}
```

I imagine this would explain why the streaming parser never actually terminates ;).

Comment: actually i am taking 1000 point from stream. but i want to notify me before ending a stream

Comment: points<-DSD_Wrapper(get_points(data_stream,n=1000));
 if(!points) this part giving error.. 
Error in get_points.DSD_Wrapper(data_stream, n = 1000) : 
  The stream is at its end!

Comment: Is that the error message you're getting? And, are you sure that, for the last iteration, there are 1,000 points still remaining in the stream? It's somewhat hard to debug without a reproducible example (in other words, an example dataset that generates this error).

Comment: i have a set of health data.
 file structure such as
  > longitude lattitude day cases
 so created a file have records around 17699997. so i have to create a stream using stream package extracting a 1000 data from a file.and then i m going to apply Denstram() algorithm for online cluster and same 1000 point get and apply offline algorithm such K-means, DBSACN. i want to take 1000 points from the file apply online and offline cluster. the aging take 1000 until the stream is going to end.but i want to notify user tha stream is end.i am unable to notify.

Comment: I meant an actual example dataset ;).

Answer (score -1):

my problem statement 
 i have a set of health data related to new york dataset.
 file structure such as

> longitude lattitude day cases '

```
 40.00    -73.25     1    1
```

so created a file have records around 17699997. so i have to create a stream using stream package extracting a 1000 data from a file.and then i m going to apply Denstram() algorithm for online cluster and same 1000 point get and apply offline algorithm such K-means, DBSACN.

i want to take 1000 points from the file apply online and offline cluster. the aging take 1000 until the stream is going to end.

so i have created the following code. but in which i unable to located the end of stream.

but i want to notify user tha stream is end.
two process

> online process
>   offline process

```
 Denstream_Dbscan<-function(Wrapper_Data_Stream)
{
  i<-1;
  while(TRUE)
  {


    # online process(micro cluster)
    start_time<-Sys.time();

    print(paste("Start online Process ",i," iteration",Sys.time()));
    dstream_micro<-DSC_DenStream(epsilon=0.01,initPoints=200,minPoints=500);
    system.time({
    cluster(dstream_micro,Wrapper_Data_Stream,n=1000,verbose=TRUE);    
    })
   # print(paste("center of cluster=",get_center(dstream_micro)));
    print(paste("no of micro cluster=",nclusters(dstream_micro,type="auto")));

    jpeg(paste("Micro Cluster(Online)_",i,".jpeg"));
    plot(dstream_micro,dsd=Wrapper_Data_Stream,pch=c(1,2),col_points="red",col_clusters="green",xlab="latitude",ylab="longitude", main=paste("TimeTaken=",start_time-end_time),sub=paste("micro cluster:",Sys.time()),col.main="red",col.sub="black");
    print(paste("End online Process  for ",i," iteration",Sys.time()));
    dev.off();


    # offline process (macro cluster)

    print(paste("Start offline Process ",i," iteration",Sys.time()));
    start_time<-Sys.time();
    dbscan_macro<-DSC_DBSCAN(eps=0.1)
    system.time({
    recluster(dbscan_macro,dstream_micro);

    })

    print(paste("no of macro cluster=",nclusters(dbscan_macro)));
   # print(paste("center of cluster=",get_center(dstream_micro)));
    end_time<-Sys.time();
    jpeg(paste("Macro Cluster(offline)_",i,".jpeg"));
    plot(dbscan_macro,Wrapper_Data_Stream,pch=c(1,2),col_points="grey",col_clusters="blue",xlab="latitude",ylab="longitude",main=paste("TimeTaken=",start_time-end_time),sub=paste("macro cluster:",Sys.time()),col.main="red",col.sub="black");
    dev.off();
    print(paste("End Offline Process  for ",i," iteration",Sys.time()));
    i<-i+1;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put this information in it.